# 3 definitions of curvature, which is it?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, differential-geometry, curvature

On the youtube lectures on differential equations by Claudi Arezzo the curvature is defined as:

(He assumes the curve is arc length parametrized maybe this matters)
$k(s) = |\alpha''(t)|$

On the open MIT course on the same topic it is defined as:

$k(t) = \frac{f''(t)}{(1 + f'(t)^2)^{3/2}}$

On wikipedia it is:

$k = \frac{y''}{(1 + y'^2)^{3/2}}$

So wikipedia and MIT agree on their definition. Which one is it? Are both correct and one is just a simplification if the curve is arclength parametrized?

I don't find that simplification:

$\frac{y''}{1 + y'^2}^{3/2} = \frac{y''}{2}^{3/2} \neq y''$

I also don't see where the denominator in this expression is coming from.

Comment: Both are correct - the first definition is when $\alpha$ is parametrised by $t$, and then the derivatives are taken w.r.t. $t$. The second is when $y$ (or $f$) is explicitly a function of $x$, and then the derivatives are taken w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: @JordanMitchellBarrett Maybe you should post that as an answer.

Comment: To be clear, the crucial difference is that the latter definitions are considering the curve formed by the **graph** of a function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R,$ while the first one is considering a parametrized curve $\alpha: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2.$ To find the correspondence, you need to let $\alpha(t) = (t, f(t))$ and then reparametrize by arclength.